# Fixing login button

Tags: javascript, html, button

When I click the login button, it does not redirect me to anything. I stay on the same page. Once the user logs in, they should be redirected to another page.

This is my current code:

```
<div class="loginContainer">
<p id="ob">Online Banking</p>
<p id="ml">Member Login</p>
<input id="userid" name="userid" type="text" placeholder="LoginID" />
<input id="mlButton" type="button" value="Login" />

<script> 
        function RedirectToLogin() { 
                var userId = document.getElementById("userid").value; 
                window.location.href = "https://www.securecuonline.com/fffcu/Login.aspx";
        } 
</script>

&nbsp;
<div><a class="links" href="/lost-or-stolen-card/">Lost or Stolen Card</a>
<a class="links" href="https://www.securecuonline.com/fffcu/Login.aspx">Make a Payment</a>
<a class="links" href=" https://www.securecuonline.com/fffcu/EnrollOnlineBanking.aspx">Register your account</a></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You never actually set up the function to be called. This should get it down with less code:

```html
<form class="loginContainer" action="/fffcu/Login.aspx">
<p id="ob">Online Banking</p>
<p id="ml">Member Login</p>
<input id="userid" name="userid" type="text" placeholder="LoginID" />
<input id="mlButton" type="submit" value="Login" />

<div><a class="links" href="/lost-or-stolen-card/">Lost or Stolen Card</a>
<a class="links" href="https://www.securecuonline.com/fffcu/Login.aspx">Make a Payment</a>
<a class="links" href=" https://www.securecuonline.com/fffcu/EnrollOnlineBanking.aspx">Register your account</a></div>
</form>
```